# Parsing XML & Output to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, powershell

I'm making a script that will parse through 2,000 XML files for data & then output it to an Excel file.
Here's what I have so far:

```
#Get XML File
$path = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\bcamareno\Desktop\xml\xml

#Start Excel
$xl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$wb=$xl.Workbooks.Add()
$ws=$wb.ActiveSheet

$cells=$ws.Cells
$cells.item(1,1)="HDD Report"
$cells.item(1,1).font.bold=$True
$cells.item(1,1).font.size=18

#Rows & Cols
$row=3
$col=1
$A=4
$B=4
$C=4
$D=1
$E=2
$F=3

#column headings
"Server","Disk0","Disk1","Disk2","Disk3","Disk4","Disk5","Disk6","Disk7" | foreach {
    $cells.item($row,$col)=$_
    $cells.item($row,$col).font.bold=$True
    $col++
}

#Site Code
foreach ($item in $Path) {
$cells.item($A,$D)= $item -replace "_pdisk.xml",""
      $A++
}

#Grab ProductID
foreach ($item in $Path) {
    [xml]$content = Get-Content "c:\Users\bcamareno\Desktop\xml\xml\$item"
    $try= $Content.SelectNodes('//ProductID') | select "#Text"
    $cells.item($B,$E)= $try -replace "@{#text=","" -replace "}",""
    $B,$E++
}

$xl.Visible=$True
```

But when I run it, the data comes out wrong, it seems like it's only parsing the last file & then adding that result to the cells.

I can add an XML if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$B` never gets incremented, so you aren't ever adding rows to the spreadsheet - just overwriting the same row 2000 times over.

I would also suggest that you use more descriptive variable names than single letters.

Also, change this line:

```
[xml]$content = Get-Content "c:\Users\bcamareno\Desktop\xml\xml\$item"
```

To this:

```
[xml]$content = Get-Content $item.FullName
```

That way, when you change the location of your XML Files, you only have to do it once (when you call `Get-ChildItem`) and aren't chasing a "bug" for 2 hours because you forgot to update all instances of that path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what's the right way to get $B and $E incremented? Because I tried several things and none of them work.

Comment: `$E` *is* getting incremented. Only `$B` isn't, because `$B,$E++` doesn't increment `$B`. Try it for yourself at a prompt: `$a=1;$b=2;$a,$b++;$a,$b++;` - `$a` remains at `1`, `$b` increments.  What you want is `$B++;$E++` (formatting a bit munged due to the limits of this comment box).

Comment: Thanks again. I changed it to what you suggested & it still comes out in the wrong order. I can send you a screenshot if you give me your email..

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/200289  this is how it's coming out.

Comment: What is the "right" order? What does your input look like? What is your output supposed to look like? You probably need 2 nested `foreach` loops - the outer one for each row (representing each XML file), the inner one for each column (representing values in the XML file). In the inner loop, you increment `$E` to work across the row, (and reset on each iteration) the outer loop increments `$B` to add rows to the spreadsheet. Or, make it all much simpler and turn your data into a 2D array (or array of hashes), and then use `Export-CSV` to output a CSV file of the data.

Comment: This is the right way: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/200911   & I did try to output it to CSV, but in that format it only gives me 1 column & I'm not sure how to assign each result to a specific column of the CSV.

Comment: I'm afraid it's almost impossible to take this any further without knowing how the XML is structured. You've provided the desired output format but without knowing the input format, it's very difficult to suggest how to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I readed this post a little late, but I did make some tests and it works for me.

```
#Grab ProductID
foreach ($item in $path) {
    [xml]$content = Get-Content "c:\Users\bcamareno\Desktop\xml\xml\$item"
    foreach ($try in  $($Content.SelectNodes('//ProductID') | select "#Text")) {
    $cells.item($B,$E)= $try -replace "@{Size=","" -replace "}",""
    $B,$E++
    }
    $B++ 
    $E=2
}
```

thanks and sorry for my pseudo-english :P